# How to get both the ID value and the NAME value from Ionic Dynamic Select Options

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-native

ionic 3, I have implemented the dynamic select option successfully, I want to be able to send the ID value and the Name value of the selected to Option to the server

as I am only able to get either the ID or the Name, I can't get both values, please help, I have tried JSON.parse, and the id.value and name.value, in the options, but sadly I am only able to get the first value and no both

````
 <ion-list >
    <ion-item class="list-but">
      <ion-label>Tipo de Ambiente</ion-label>
      <ion-select
        [(ngModel)]="idType"
        multiple="false"
        cancelText="Cancelar"
        okText="Ok"
      >
        <ion-option
          *ngFor="let type of type_environment"
          value="{{ type.name }}"
          value="{{ type.id }}"
          #name
          >{{ type.name }}</ion-option
        >
      </ion-select>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
  <button ion-button block (click)="insert()">Salvar</button>


``public type_environment = new Array<any>();
  public idType: number = 0;
  public nameType: string = "name";
  private userData: any;`
```

insert() {
    this.userData = this.user.getUserData();

    let body = {
      name: this.nameType,
      id_type: this.idType,
      id_unity: this.navParams.get("id.unidade")
    };
    console.log("name:", this.idType);

    this.route.postData("/ambiente", body).subscribe(
      data => {
        let response = data as any;

        let ret = JSON.parse(response._body);

        if (ret.insertId) {
          this.navCtrl.popToRoot();
        } else {
          console.log(ret);
        }
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error);
````

Comment: If this is a multiple select, you would actually get an array, but you seem to want to pass just **one** object??

Comment: yes i want to pass just one object with the ID as a Value and the Name as a second Value

Comment: then why do you have `multiple="true"`?

Comment: I am sorry,  forgot to correct it during posting

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to have two `value` in your select, just have bind the whole object to `value`, i.e:

```html
<ion-select [(ngModel)]="idType" cancelText="Cancelar" okText="Ok">
  <ion-option *ngFor="let type of type_environment" [value]="type">
    {{ type.name }}
  </ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

After this, you have your object value in `idType`:

```ts
insert() { 
  // below is your chosen object and its properties
  console.log(this.idType.id, this.idType.name)
}
```

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-fxeij2?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html)**

Comment: This solved my problem, thank you very much, you're a life saver, thanks again.

Comment: No problem, glad to hear it helped :) Since it helped, you can consider accepting the answer by clicking the grey tick under the voting of this answer, which marks the question as solved. Have a good one and happy coding! :)